# Unable to install nltk in 64 bit version on python 3.6.3

Tags: python, anaconda, nltk

when I do the steps for the nltk download on anaconda prompt the nltk window opens but there is a

```
Errno 11004 getaddrinfo failed
```

Can anyone please let me know how to solve this?

Comment: getaddressinfo failed generally means it cannot connect. are you behind some proxy?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to install on my office laptop. How can I deactivate the proxy

Comment: depends on the machine and you may have to check with your IT